# How to execute "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS" queries in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get status information using Laravel. In short, I want to execute commands like `show global status like "Com_select";` and store data in a variable. But I am facing an issue.

When I try to execute commands like `show global status like "Com_select";` using `DB:: statement()` command, It returns boolean like `true`. I don't know why so but it does.

When I try to do this using `DB::raw()`, It just stores the query in variable. I was never a fan of `DB::raw()` because if it's weird behavior.

Is there any way to get this done directly from laravel?

Comment: Statements don't typically return tabular results but only have a success or failure. As I understand it a show status is more similar to a select so according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries you should use `\DB::select`

Comment: It worked brother! :D